# How to delete old IAM Credentials in Perfect Assistant - Server Side swift?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, perfect

I am trying to delete old IAM Credentials in Perfect Assistant? of course I know how to delete IAM credentials in AWS but I need to clear it on my mac for Perfect Assistant. I can't find the instructions anywhere here or in google search how to do that. Any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the ~/.aws directory.  There is a file  ~/.aws/credentials where the credentials are stored.  This is a function of the AWS commandline toolkit, not Perfect Assist.